# php array values deletes an index

Tags: php, arrays, arraylist, jquery-ui-sortable

I have array of objects, what I want to do is reset the index like 123, 150, 50 to be 0,1,2 . I have done array_values(); but it removes the first array "123".

How can I make the index numbers starting from 0 . to make 123, 150, 50, to become 0,1,2

```
     array(
    123 =>
      User::__set_state(array(
    _type' => 'student',
    'id' =>'23'}),
    150=>
    User::__set_state(array(
    '_type' => 'student',
   'id' =>'29'}),
    50=>
    User::__set_state(array(
    '_type' => 'student',
    'id' =>'12'})
```

The output

```
         array(
     150=>
    User::__set_state(array(
    '_type' => 'student',
   'id' =>'29'}),
    50=>
    User::__set_state(array(
    '_type' => 'student',
    'id' =>'12'})
```

Comment: array_values removing an index ? strange... can you give us the exact input and output ?

Comment: thanks, but can you use var_dump instead to write input and output ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`array_values`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) is correct solution. The little thing is that it does not affect given array, but returns an array. So you have to assign it to another variable. For example:

```
$arr1 = array(123 => 'test', 1234 => 'test2');
$arr2 = array_values($arr1);
print_r($arr2); //prints: Array ([0] => test [1] => test2)
```